Why are $SO(N)$ symmetries often associated with bosons, and $SU(N)$ with fermions in particle physics?
In the context of particle physics, I’ve often seen $SO(N)$ symmetries linked with bosonic fields and $SU(N)$ symmetries with fermionic fields. I understand that bosons have integer spins and obey Bose-Einstein statistics, while fermions have half-integer spins and obey Fermi-Dirac statistics. However, I’m looking for a deeper explanation of why specific symmetry groups align with these two types of particles.

What is the fundamental reason for associating $SO(N)$ with bosons and $SU(N)$ with fermions?
How do the properties of $SO(N)$ and $SU(N)$, like their representations, connect with the spin-statistics theorem and particle exchange symmetries?
Are there cases in particle physics where this association does not hold, or where both bosons and fermions transform under the same type of group?

Any insights into the underlying mathematical structures or physical principles that make $SO(N)$ and $SU(N)$ naturally suited to bosons and fermions respectively would be greatly appreciated.

The Higgs doublet is a rep of SU(2).

The weak/strong gauge Bosons are associated with $SU(2)/SU(3)$

$SU(3)$ is used both for color charge of quarks (i.e. fermions) and of gluons (i.e. bosons).

Often seen where?

It's not completely clear what you mean but here's a possible answer based on

Robert Gilmore, Lie groups, Lie algebras and some of their applications (1974) edition, Chapter 10, problem 14.

This is the last chapter of the text so there are prerequisites on roots and weights but roughly things go as follows.  I will use $f_i, f_j^\dagger$ for fermion operators and $b_i, b_j^\dagger$ for bosons.
Start with an n-dimensional space with basis $\{\vert i\rangle,i=1,\ldots,n\}$, and the set of operators $C_{ij}=\vert i\rangle\langle j\vert$.  It's easy enough to verify that
$$
[C_{ij},C_{km}]=C_{im}\delta_{jk}-C_{kj}\delta_{im}
$$
which are the commutation relations of $\mathfrak{u}(n)$.  You can easily verify that the sets of number-preserving bilinears
$$
F_{ij}=f_i^\dagger f_j\, ,\quad B_{ij}=b_i^\dagger b_j
$$
separately satisfy those commutation relations so the number-preserving bilinears in the fermionic or bosonic operators actually both span $\mathfrak{u}(n)$.
The difference in statistics arises with non-number-preserving bilinears.  For instance the set
$$
f_i^\dagger f_j^\dagger\, ,\quad f_i f_j\, ,\quad f_i^\dagger f_j
$$
Clearly because these are fermionic operators you cannot have
$f_i^\dagger f_i^\dagger$ so given some vacuum $\vert -\rangle$ killed all $f_j$'s you can only generate finitely many states by repeated application of the $f_i^\dagger f_j^\dagger$ and $f_i^\dagger f_j$. In fact, Gilmore discusses how these map to the roots
$$
f_i^\dagger f_i\mapsto H_i\, ,\quad f_i^\dagger f_j\mapsto E_{\mathbf{e}_i-\mathbf{e}_j}\, ,\qquad f_i^\dagger f_j^\dagger \mapsto E_{\mathbf{e}_i+\mathbf{e}_j}\, ,\qquad f_if_j \mapsto E_{-\mathbf{e}_i-\mathbf{e}_j}\, ,
$$
which is the root system of $\mathfrak{so}(n)$.  It's a simple exercise if you know how to manipulate roots of an algebra to show that the map actually works so bilinears in fermion operators, when including number-changing operators, actually maps to the orthogonal algebras, not the unitary ones.
Now redo the same with non-number-preserving bosons
$$
b_i^\dagger b_j^\dagger\, ,\quad b_i b_j\, ,\quad b_i^\dagger b_j
$$
Given some vacuum $\vert -\rangle$ killed all $b_j$'s you can ladder up with $b_i^\dagger b_j^\dagger$ as much as you want, so the resulting space of states is infinite dimensional.  That's a hint that, because unitary irreducible representations of non-compact groups must be infinite-dimensional, what you have here is in fact a non-compact (real form) of some algebra, which again you can identify by mapping operators to roots
$$
b_i^\dagger b_i\mapsto H_i\, ,\quad b_i^\dagger b_j\mapsto E_{\mathbf{e}_i-\mathbf{e}_j}\, ,\qquad b_i^\dagger b_j^\dagger \mapsto E_{\mathbf{e}_i+\mathbf{e}_j}\, ,\qquad b_ib_j \mapsto E_{-\mathbf{e}_i-\mathbf{e}_j}\, ,
$$
as before, but because of statistics you can also have
$$
b_i^\dagger b_i^\dagger\mapsto E_{2\mathbf{e}_i}\, ,\qquad 
b_i b_i \mapsto E_{-2\mathbf{e}_i}\, ,
$$
and altogether you get the root system of $\mathfrak{sp}(2n,\mathbb{R})$.  Thus, here the bosons maps to generators of the real symplectic algebra.  The bosonic case has extra roots like $E_{2\mathbf{e}_i}$ which correcspond to $b_i^\dagger b_i^\dagger$ or $b_i b_i$ that obviously cannot occur in the fermionic case.
